# Insert into SQL Server date using Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

I'm using PowerShell to import a `.CSV` file and I need to save its contents to a database.

I'm using the code below to pull information from the `.CSV` file, and put it into the database

```
foreach($row in $data) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Offerings (RATING, PARVALUE, DESCRIPTION, COUPON, MATURITY, DATEDDATE, CALLDATE, FIRSTCOUPON, CUSIP, PRICEYIELD, COM) VALUES( `
    '$(($row.rating).trim())', `
    '$(($row."PAR VALUE").trim())',`
    '$(($row.DESCRIPTION).trim())', `
    '$(($row.COUPON).trim())', `
    '$(($row.MATURITY))', `
    '$(([datetime]$row."DATED DATE"))', `
    '$(($row."CALL DATE").trim())', `
    '$(($row."FIRST COUPON"))', `
    '$(($row.CUSIP).trim())', `
    '$(($row."PRICE/YIELD").trim())',`
    '$(($row.COM).trim())' `
    )"

    $command.CommandText = $sql
    $command.ExecuteNonQuery() | out-null
}
```

The columns `$row.MATURITY`/`$row."CALL DATE"` and `$row."FIRST COUPON"` are all dates (the columns in the database are of type `DATE`).

But the insert is passing it as a string, which the database complains that it can't convert string to DATE. How can I pass it as a date in the PowerShell command so it will write correctly to the database (as `DATE` type)?

Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way is to insert into a staging table whose columns are varchar data type, and then you can transform data in staging table to your designated table.

Comment: I dont know the format of your data. But you should be able to something like this for your `$row.Maturity` : `'$((Get-Date $row.MATURITY -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))', `

Comment: You probably need to convert it to a date in SQL. That is to say the SQL command that you execute from powershell should utilize a database function like TO_DATE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String concatenation is a very bad idea.  It doesn't just open your code to SQL injection, it's extremely fragile.

Use a parameterized query.  Assuming you're using SQL Server:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Offerings (RATING, PARVALUE, DESCRIPTION, COUPON, MATURITY, DATEDDATE, CALLDATE, FIRSTCOUPON, CUSIP, PRICEYIELD, COM) " +
    "VALUES (@RATING, @PARVALUE, @DESCRIPTION, @COUPON, @MATURITY, @DATEDDATE, @CALLDATE, @FIRSTCOUPON, @CUSIP, @PRICEYIELD, @COM)"

$command.CommandText = $sql

# Add your parameters and define their types to match the types in the Offerings table
# The System.Data.SqlDbType type includes all SQL Server data types
# For data type mapping, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings
[void]$command.Parameters.Add('@RATING', [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar)
[void]$command.Parameters.Add('@PARVALUE', [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar)
[void]$command.Parameters.Add('@DESCRIPTION', [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar)
[void]$command.Parameters.Add('@COUPON', [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar)
[void]$command.Parameters.Add('@MATURITY', [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Date)
[void]$command.Parameters.Add('@DATEDDATE', [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Date)
[void]$command.Parameters.Add('@CALLDATE', [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Date)
[void]$command.Parameters.Add('@FIRSTCOUPON', [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar)
[void]$command.Parameters.Add('@CUSIP', [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar)
[void]$command.Parameters.Add('@PRICEYIELD', [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar)
[void]$command.Parameters.Add('@COM', [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar)
# I've defaulted to NVARCHAR here, but you should use the appropriate column data type

foreach ($row in $data) {
    # Set the values of each parameter
    $command.Parameters['@RATING'].Value      = $row.rating.trim()
    $command.Parameters['@PARVALUE'].Value    = $row."PAR VALUE".trim()
    $command.Parameters['@DESCRIPTION'].Value = $row.DESCRIPTION.trim()
    $command.Parameters['@COUPON'].Value      = $row.COUPON.trim()
    $command.Parameters['@MATURITY'].Value    = [datetime]$row.MATURITY
    $command.Parameters['@DATEDDATE'].Value   = [datetime]$row."DATED DATE"
    $command.Parameters['@CALLDATE'].Value    = [datetime]$row."CALL DATE"
    $command.Parameters['@FIRSTCOUPON'].Value = $row."FIRST COUPON"
    $command.Parameters['@CUSIP'].Value       = $row.CUSIP.trim()
    $command.Parameters['@PRICEYIELD'].Value  = $row."PRICE/YIELD".trim()
    $command.Parameters['@COM'].Value         = $row.COM.trim()

    [void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
```

Your code may vary slightly if you're using a different RDBMS than SQL Server.

If you're having trouble converting strings in `$row` into datetimes, you can use the ParseExact function:

```
$command.Parameters['@MATURITY'].Value    = [datetime]::ParseExact($row.MATURITY, 'dd.MM.yyyy', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Or you can use `Get-Date`

```
$command.Parameters['@MATURITY'].Value    = Get-Date $row.MATURITY -Format 'dd.MM.yyyy'
```

The only complicated part of parameterized queries is that if you need to set a value to NULL in the databse, then the value of the parameter needs to be `[System.DBNull]::Value`, not `$null`.